# iOS App is crashing

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash

I am writing a static library for iOS devices. Using xcode 3.2.6, selected Latest iOS 4.3 for compilation and selected iOS 3.1.2 for deployment. Keeping all the settings default, Library is using multiple frameworks like Security. 
    For testing, i first wrote this lib as application, and calling function from main file only just before `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`. So all this executed perfectly.

```
Now if I added UI components and calling functions as per user select an option, my application starts crashing randomly or aborted abnormally.

Latest crash Log is as follows:



    B61B817A-CB86-4B3D-A2BE-5CAFC9AFC857

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
    Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000012
    Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Application Specific Information:
    objc_msgSend() selector name: objectForKey:
    iPhone Simulator 238.2, iPhone OS 4.3 (iPad/8F192)
    iPhone Simulator 238.2, iPhone OS 4.3 (iPad/8F192)


    Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0103109b objc_msgSend + 15
    1   ???                             0x000600b8 OBJC_CLASS_$_MPLogHndlr + 0
    2   iTestApp                    0x0004267a -[Record2 getInfo] + 113 (Record2.m:609)
    3   iTestApp                    0x000434c1 -[Record2 getAllInfo:] + 44 (Record2.m:798)
    4   iTestApp                    0x00016919 -[BasicInfo getInfo] + 70 (BasicInfo.m:238)
    5   iTestApp                    0x000283bf -[AllInfo init:] + 1724 (AllInfo.m:55)
    6   iTestApp                    0x00012130 -[Emp getEmpInfo] + 461 (Emp.m:1175)
    7   iTestApp                    0x00003808 -[iTestApp ViewController btnApiGo_Clicked:] + 2155 (iTestApp ViewController.m:274)
    8   UIKit                           0x0032f4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    9   UIKit                           0x003bf799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                           0x003c1c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    11  UIKit                           0x003c07d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    12  UIKit                           0x00353ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    13  UIKit                           0x00334c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    14  UIKit                           0x00339f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    15  GraphicsServices                0x01b18992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x00eac944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x00e0ccf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x00e09f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x00e09840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x00e09761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                0x01b171c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                0x01b17289 GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                           0x0033dc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  iTestApp                    0x00001f14 main + 102 (main.m:14)
    25  iTestApp                    0x00001ea5 start + 53
```

Here is the code :

```
- (int) getInfo
{
    @try{
        Field   *f = [self gField:F_NAME];
        int index = [self getFIndex:f];

        return [f findValAtIndex:index]; <=== 609 
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) 
    {
        MpDebugTrace(@"Exception : <%@> %@", [e name], [e reason]);
        @throw; // re-throws exception
    }
    return -1;
}


    - (int) findValAtIndex:(int) idx
    {
        NSString *key  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", idx];

        // vals is NSMutableDictionary
        NSNumber *valForKey = [vals objectForKey:key];
        return  [valForKey intValue];
    }
```

Comment: Does the `Field` class have a method `findValAtIndex` as well? Or did you want to call `[self findValAtIndex:index]` instead?

Comment: Well function findValAtIndex is of class Field. Evereything is in -placed. It is just one place where the code is crashing. It crashes at random points.